# f:selectItem inside ui:repeat - doesn't work

Tags: jsf, uirepeat, selectmanycheckbox

I want to loop through List and make each element a checkbox. The code which i have is:

```
<h:outputText value="Choose" />
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{filterTypeBean.selectedFilterTypes}">
    <ui:repeat var="checkbox" value="#{filterTypeBean.listFilterTypes()}"
        varStatus="status">
        <!-- <h:outputText value="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}" /> -->
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}"
            itemValue="#{checkbox}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

My bean class contains:

```
private List<FilterType> selectedFilterTypes;

public List<TFilterType> getSelectedFilterTypes() {
        return selectedFilterTypes;
}

public void setSelectedFilterTypes(List<TFilterType> selectedFilterTypes) {
    this.selectedFilterTypes = selectedFilterTypes;
}

public List<FilterType> listFilterTypes() {
        EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select u from FilterType u");
        List<FilterType> filterList = q.getResultList();
        for (FilterType filterType : filterList) {
            System.out.println(filterType.getFilterTypeName());
        }
        return filterList;
    }
```

I don't got the expected result - no checkboxes appear in the filterList (I have nothing on the screen).If i uncomment the line for printing the names of Filter Type 
 -->
I got the names. Please, help me to fix this issue.

Comment: There is `f:selectItems` for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `f:selectItems` instead, replace

```
<ui:repeat var="checkbox" value="#{filterTypeBean.listFilterTypes()}"
    varStatus="status">
    <!-- <h:outputText value="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}" /> -->
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}"
        itemValue="#{checkbox}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

by something like

```
<f:selectItems var="checkbox" value="#{filterTypeBean.listFilterTypes()}" itemLabel="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}" itemValue="#{checkbox}" />
```

but I don't think your `itemValue="#{checkbox}"` will work since this your entire object containing description too.

**More info :**

- [f:selectItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html)